# Dialogflow: How to set up an intent which receiver any user keyword/utterance

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

This is what i want to build:
I am building a chatbot to search in an archive. When the users says he wants to search the archive dialogflow provides quick replies with the archive document type, when the user click on a quick reply i get the entity **ArchiveSearchTopic** (for instance Photos, or Newspapers) and i use it as a filter for the archive search, the agent responds back to the user with the number of items found and asks the users to provide a keyword (**n keywords, or a sentence**) to search within the filtered items.

Thanks in advance.

I tried with a **followup fallback intent**, but it does not get triggered because it needs training phrases as well.

Here an example fo the conversational flow:
**U**: user, **A**: Agent

U: I want to search the archive (Trigger **searchArchive** intent)

A: Sure, pick now of the topics: PHOTOS, NEWSPAPERS, DRAWINGS (quick replies)

U: Clicks on PHOTOS (Trigger **searchArchive.provideSearchTopic** intent, extract the **ArchiveSearchTopiEntity**)

A: I found XXX items about PHOTOS, do you want to see all results or maybe you are looking for something specific?

U: motorbike and bike shows in Taurin (**this is the intent i need to find out how to set up**)

I can't find out how to build an intent which accepts whatever the users says in order to search the archive with the entity filter + the search keyword/sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use fulfilments: to get the full content of the message the user said, use:

```
let query = agent.query
```

See the code here: [[Github]](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/8bcea44eb3cf931d9ba316b273a59be672d0da63/src/v2-agent.js#L129)

Comment: Hello @plieb and thanks. According to you i should put some logic in the default fallback intent fulfillment so if the archive search contexts are active i get the whole user query? I'd rather have a 1to1 mapping with intent -> fulfillment. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can know if the next interaction is going to be a search, if yes you should be able to set the context to force a fulfilment?